# AWS Reserved RDS Billing Status

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-reserved-instances

Hey quick question related to aws reserved rds.
Just need to know that in order for reserved plan to work, do we need to create rds instance or cluster [as new resource] after we purchase the plan or it can work if we have rds instance running earlier before we purchase the plan.
Thanks

Comment: Reserved instances are purely a billing thing. They are not tied to any specific instances. If you have an instance on the bill within your reserved plan, the discount will be applied.

Comment: So you guide me how view my change in billing plan, as my billing dashboard shows charges for both my running db instance and reserved plan as separate.

Comment: Can't place screen shot, but maybe below will be of some help
Copied from billing dashboard

Amazon Relational Database Service for Aurora PostgreSQL
some billing detail
Amazon Relational Database Service for Aurora PostgreSQL Reserved Instances
some billing detail

Billing dashboard is showing my bill as a total of both...